# Insert Multidimensional Array into Database with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

how can I insert this array into my database? supposing I already have a database?

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['myname'], $_POST['myage'], $_POST['mygen']) === true){
```

> //this is the code where I set the keys and values

```
$array = array($_POST['myname'], $_POST['myage'], $_POST['mygen']);

foreach ($array as $i => $values) {
    print "<pre>$i {\n";
    foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
        print "    $key => $value\n";
    }
    print "}\n</pre>";
}
}




?>
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
function CreateTextbox()
```

> //I generate textbox dynamically by this code

```
{
createTextbox.innerHTML = createTextbox.innerHTML +"Name: <input type='text' name='myname[]' /><br>"
+"Age: <input type='text' name='myage[]' /><br>"
+"Gender: <input type='text' name='mygen[]' /><br>" 
}
    </script>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div id="createTextbox"></div>
            <input type="button" value="clickHere" onClick="CreateTextbox()" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

please help :(

Comment: Do you want to store the array itself in the database or do you want to store the values in the array into individual database fields?

Comment: Also, what database?  Some databases actually *have* array types.

Comment: @MikeBrant  i want to store the array into individual database fields, for example

i want this particular array to be stored in different rows in the database, im using phpmyadmin BTW

0 {
    0 => Jake
    1 => Sheryl
}
1 {
    0 => 20
    1 => 19
}
2 {
    0 => male
    1 => female
}

Comment: $_POST['myname'], $_POST['myage'], $_POST['mygen'] are also arrays

Comment: OK. phpmyadmin is not a database.  It as a GUI tool for working with MySQL databases.  It sounds like you are just trying to learn how to insert data into a MySQL database with PHP, which is a much more exhaustive topic.  I would simply reference you to the online PHP documentation.

Comment: Sir @MikeBrant, I'm having a difficult time manipulating arrays, I know how to Insert data into MySQL database with Php but when it comes to arrays, I'm really having a hard time with it :(, especially when the data comes from automatically generated textboxes

Comment: I see, so the problem is you may have some form data with a variable amount of fields that you need to figure out how to relate to each other?  Can you post sample dumps of the variables?

Comment: I've already edited the code above sir @MikeBrant

Comment: Ok that helps. In that I can see that you will always be generating one each of the myname, myage, and mygen text boxes such that you should have the same number of each, and their positions within the arrays should match (i.e. the first array element for myname will match with the first element from myage, etc.).  So look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could need to count the amount of elements in the incoming post arrays like this

```
$data_count = count($_POST['myname']);
```

You may also consider here adding some errro handling to verify the size of all the post array are the same, but I will skip that.

Then you want to loop through the arrays and do your DB inserts like this:

```
for ($i=0; $i<$data_count; $i++) {
    $name = $_POST['myname'][$i];
    $age = $_POST['myage'][$i];
    $gen = $_POST['mygen'][$i];
    // clean up data for DB insert here 
    // make DB insert
}
```

Note that I have left out the actual code for cleaning the data and inserting the data, as thiat is kind of out of the scope of this discussion.